# How to express "if any component in a vector satisfies that ..." in Mathematica

Tags: list-manipulation

For example, `l` is a list of vectors. I need to delete from `l` all the vectors with any component larger than 1. How should I do that?

```
DeleteCases[l, x__ /; MemberQ[x, _ /; # < 1 &]]
```

Did not work. Thanks!

Comment: Additionally to my answer below, I just came across another way using `VectorQ` and I remembered this post. You can do also : `Cases[listofvectors, x_?(VectorQ [#, # < 1 &] &)]` or `Cases[listofvectors, x_ /; VectorQ[x, # < 1 &] ]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make a test on each component of a list of vectors :

```
(* Here is the test list : *)
listofvectors = {{0., 1.1, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.25, 0.}, {2., 3., 4.}};
```

you can use :

**1.PatternTest**

```
Cases[listofvectors, {components__?(# < 1 &)}]
(*{{0.5, 0.25, 0.}}*)
```

This picks out of the vectors where **each** component is <1.

(The symbol `?`stands here for `PatternTest`(see the [doc](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html)))

Note that this is not the same that :

```
DeleteCases[listofvectors, {components__?(# > 1 &)}]
(*{{0., 1.1, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.25, 0.}}*)
```

because it means that we want to delete the vectors where, again, **each** component is >1. If one (or more) component is < 1, the vector won't be deleted.

**2.Condition**

Using the `/;`, you can also test individually each component :

```
Cases[listofvectors, {___, component_, ___} /; component < 1]
Cases[listofvectors, {___, component_ /; component < 1, ___} ]
(*{{0., 1.1, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.25, 0.}}*)
```

but with the new pattern here, the selected vectors do not require to have all the components <1 ...

So here you can use instead :

```
DeleteCases[listofvectors, {___, component_, ___} /; component > 1]
DeleteCases[listofvectors, {___, component_ /; component > 1, ___} ]
(*{{0.5, 0.25, 0.}}*)
```

which deletes vectors as soon as one component is >1.

Answer (score 3):

```
L0 = {{.4, .2, 1000}, {.5, .4, .7}, {.5, .7, .9, .99}};
DeleteCases[L0, x_ /; Max[x] > 1]

(* {{0.5, 0.4, 0.7}, {0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 0.99}} *)
```

ps. You can also use [Norm](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Norm.html) if you know the norm you want:

```
L0 = {{.4, .2, 1000}, {.5, .4, .7}, {.5, .7, .9, .99}};
DeleteCases[L0, x_ /; Norm[x, Infinity] > 1]
```

Comment: Could you explain why `MemberQ` did not work please?

Comment: @AlexSu ny guess it has to do with overloading of `x` in 2 places, I am not sure. But this works: `DeleteCases[L0, x_ /; MemberQ[x, z_ /; z > 1]]`

Answer (score 1):

Just some variants:

test:`vl = {{.4, .2, 1000}, {.5, .4, .7}, {.5, .7, .9, .99}};`

```
Cases[vl, _?(Max@# < 1 &)]
Select[vl, Max[#] < 1 &]
Pick[vl, Max[#] < 1 & /@ vl]
True /. GroupBy[vl, Max[#] < 1 &]
Pick[vl,Norm[#,Infinity]<1&/@val] (*inspired by Nasser*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a test list of vectors :

```
listofvectors = {{0., 1.1, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.25, 0.}, {2., 3., 4.}, {1.3, 1.1, 0.2}}
```

The closest solutions to what you propose in your post are :

```
DeleteCases[listofvectors, {x__} /; MemberQ[{x}, _?(# > 1 &)]]
DeleteCases[listofvectors, vec_ /; MemberQ[vec, _?(# > 1 &)]]
DeleteCases[listofvectors, vec_ /; MemberQ[vec, x_ /; x > 1]]
```

or

```
Cases[listofvectors, {x__} /; FreeQ[{x}, _?(# > 1 &)]]
Cases[listofvectors, vec_ /; FreeQ[vec, _?(# > 1 &)]]
Cases[listofvectors, vec_ /; FreeQ[vec, x_ /; x > 1]]
```

All give :

```
{{0.5, 0.25, 0.}}
```